# LUIS cannot edit hierarchical entity to add a new child

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

Well, the subject line tells it all. I have only 3 entities and all are hierarchical with less than 10 children. When I try to add a new child to any of these the app hangs with a yellow ribbon on the page top saying "Updating .."
Is this normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a temporary limitation in the portal that will be fixed soon.

In the interim you can work around this by calling the REST APIs to modify the existing entity.  Here is a step by step of adding a new child entity 'Middle' to an existing 'Children' hierarchical entity which contains 'First' and 'Last':

1. Get your Programmatic API key (https://www.luis.ai/home/keys)
2. Get the application ID and Version (https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c30/console)

   [image: Get app ID and version]
3. Get Hierarchical Entity ID (https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c11/console)

   [image: Get Hierarchical Entity ID]
4. Update model (https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c21)

   [image: Update Model]